# I am using solr-4.0. - what exact disance should i used for fuzzy seach after ~

Tags: vb.net, solr

I am using solr-4.0. I need to make fuzzy search I am appending '~' at the end of word. 
E.g if am searching healht~0.5 it gives me correct list health document however If I search for Healht drugs~0.5 it is not giving result for health document
Thought I am appending~0.5 using function for each world  it will resolve the issue  Healht~0.5 drugs~0.5 but ultimately It will create issue for &,and for space  >my search   search query : title:(healht~0.5 drugs~0.5)

Also I want to know what will the correct distance I have to applied after '~'  which will gove me correct result  if short what will be difference between using 
~0.5,~0.8,~1.0,~2.0

Can anyone help me for above issue and question

Answer (score 0):

What exact distance you should use depend on your use case - exactly how much fuzziness makes sense for the type of documents and queries you're supporting. The only way to really test this is to measure the response from your users and whether they find the results relevant or not. The parameter can be between 0 and 1, with the default being 0.5 if not given (i.e. if you're just searching for Healht~).

Fuzziness has to be given per word, and uses the Damerau–Levenshtein algorithm. It does not support more than two edits.

Comment: Thanks for respond - just for more clarification of  the concept 

Is it possible to provide some  example when to use 0.1 and when to use 0.5 or 0.7 – 

if  I am using healht~0.1 it is giving me same result as using ~0.5

Comment: Since the gap is only consider as 1 or 2 now for fuzzy search using the current algorithm, you probably won't see any difference except for between 0.5 and 1. You'll use the lower if you want more exact matches (i.e. where the edit distance is one, while an edit distance of two (~1)will give more fuzziness). Exactly which one is correct depends on your use case.

Comment: Thanks for response 

Is it good to use boosting along with the fuzzy search like (healht~0.5 drugs~0.5)^100
or it is better to use separate to avoid impact on exiting boosting functionality

Comment: That _really_ depends on your use case. Experiment to get the results you want.

Comment: Hi MatsLindh,

Is it this expected behavior or not

I am searching the document with health keyword and it is giving me 250 counts of records. However when I am searching the record documents with healht ~2 it is giving me 200 records.

Why this is happening it should be giving same result as normal search